# How to order books by users rate

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I'm trying to retrieve all books by users rating desc:

I'm keeping rates in a middle table BooksRates because there will be multiple rates for same book, and now I want to retrieve first 10 most rated books from database in one query with rates also.

For example:

> Harry Potter 4.5 Rate

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.AVG(T2.Rate) AS Rate
    FROM Books AS T1 
    INNER JOIN BookRates as T2
    ON T1.BookId = T2.BookId
    GROUP BY T1.BookId
    ORDER BY Rate desc
```

This query isn't returning the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

First you get the average `Rate` for each `BookId` with `group by` and then join to `Books` to get each book's details:

```
SELECT b.*, g.Rate FROM Books AS b INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT T1.BookId, AVG(T2.Rate) AS Rate
    FROM Books AS T1 
    INNER JOIN BookRates as T2
    ON T1.BookId = T2.BookId
    GROUP BY T1.BookId
) AS g on g.BookId = b.BookId
ORDER BY g.Rate desc
```

If there are books that are not rated then you must use a left join:

```
SELECT b.*, coalesce(g.Rate, 0) AS Rate FROM Books AS b LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT T1.BookId, AVG(T2.Rate) AS Rate
    FROM Books AS T1 
    INNER JOIN BookRates as T2
    ON T1.BookId = T2.BookId
    GROUP BY T1.BookId
) AS g on g.BookId = b.BookId
ORDER BY coalesce(g.Rate, 0) desc
```